# Is there a way to encapsulate a pattern in F#?

Tags: f#

Is there a way to encapsulate a pattern in F#?

For example, instead of writing this...

```
let stringToMatch = "example1"

match stringToMatch with
| "example1" | "example2" | "example3" -> ...
| "example4" | "example5" | "example6" -> ...
| _ -> ...
```

Is there some way to accomplish something along these lines...

```
let match1to3 = | "example1" | "example2" | "example3"
let match4to6 = | "example4" | "example5" | "example6"

match stringToMatch with
| match1to3 -> ...
| match4to6 -> ...
| _ -> ...
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this with Active Patterns:

```
let (|Match1to3|_|) text = 
    match text with
    | "example1" | "example2" | "example3" -> Some text
    | _ -> None

let (|Match4to6|_|) text = 
    match text with
    | "example4" | "example5" | "example6" -> Some text
    | _ -> None

match stringToMatch with
| Match1to3 text -> ....
| Match4to6 text -> ....
| _ -> ...
```

Comment: Perfect! Not only did you answer my question, but Active Patterns just clicked for me. Thanks!

Comment: little nitpicking, to match the initial code more closely the **Partial** Active Patterns' return should be `Some ()` and the match should be just `MatchXtoY -> ...`

Comment: Also, could have made the matchers a bit more terse by using `function` instead of `match text with`.